# Cannot get input from user to work in place of manual strings entered in code

Tags: c, string, input, getchar

I am trying to get a program to run that basically takes an input string and sends it through some code and sorts it using linked lists alphabetically.  I have figured out how to make this work using manual (in the actual code) text input, but I cannot get it to work when I am trying to take input from the user.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct llist {
    char *value;
    struct llist *next;
};

int compare (struct llist *one , struct llist *two)
{
return strcmp(one->value, two->value);
}

void add(struct llist **pp, char *value, int (*cmp)(struct llist *l, struct llist *r)) {

    struct llist *new;
    new = malloc(sizeof(*new));
    new->value = value;

    for ( ; *pp != NULL; pp = &(*pp)->next) {
        if (cmp(*pp, new) > 0 ) break;
        }

    new->next = *pp;
    *pp = new;
}

void display(struct llist *ptr) {

    for (; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->next) {
        printf("%s\n", ptr->value);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    struct llist *root = NULL;
    char string;

    printf("Please enter a string to be sorted alphabetically and displayed with a character count: ");
    string = getchar();

    while (string != 10){
    add(&root,&string, compare);
    string = getchar();

    }

    display(root);

    return 0;
}
```

looking in the main function I'm quite certain it has something to do with getchar and the fact that it reads characters in as ints, but I can't figure out how to fix this, the output is just a bunch of empty lines.  but when the while loop is removed and the strings are entered like below in main, it works fine?  why is this so?

```
int main(void) {
    struct llist *root = NULL;
    char string;

    printf("Please enter a string to be sorted alphabetically and displayed with a character count: ");

    add(&root,"t", compare);
    add(&root,"h", compare);
    add(&root,"i", compare);
    add(&root,"s", compare);
    add(&root,"m", compare);
    add(&root,"y", compare);
    add(&root,"t", compare);
    add(&root,"e", compare);
    add(&root,"x", compare);
    add(&root,"t", compare);

    display(root);

    return 0;
}
```

the output is now
e
h
i
m
s
t
t
t
x
y

which is correct,
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Note: Why use `string != 10` instead of `string != '\n'`?

Comment: I originally was using that, I don't know why I changed it exactly, but I switched it back since it does make more sense

Comment: Code is "comparing" via `strcmp()` which takes strings.  The field `value` is a copy of `&string`, a pointer to `char` but without a `'\0'` terminator.

Comment: yeah, that's what shf301 said, and I fixed it but it still did nothing to help my output unfortunately :/

Answer (score 1):

When you write `"t"` in the example, you get the address of an array.  That address is different for each value you pass to `add`.  However, the address of string does not change, and you are setting `new->value` to the same thing each time you call `add`.  Instead of `new->value = value`, try `new->value = *value` (and all of the associated changes necessary).

There are not too many changes needed.  Note that terminating after a single string of input is not very nice behavior.  A good exercise would be to write a destructor that tears down the string after the first line and then sorts the next.  Another nice exercise would be to sort arguments if any are passed, reading stdin if no arguments are given.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct llist {
        char value;    /* CHANGE */
        struct llist *next;
};


typedef int (*compar)( struct llist *one , struct llist *two );


int
compare( struct llist *one , struct llist *two )
{
        return tolower( one->value ) > tolower( two->value );  /* CHANGE */
}


void *
xmalloc( size_t s )
{
        void *v = malloc( s );
        if( v == NULL ) {
                perror( "malloc" );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
        return v;
}


void
add( struct llist **pp, char value, compar cmp ) /* CHANGE */
{

        struct llist *new;
        new = xmalloc( sizeof *new );  /* Check for errors */
        new->value = value;  /* CHANGE the type of value above */

        for( ; *pp != NULL; pp = &(*pp)->next ) {
                if( cmp( *pp, new ) > 0 )
                        break;
        }

        new->next = *pp;
        *pp = new;
}

void
display( struct llist *ptr )
{
        for( ; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->next ) {
                putchar( ptr->value );  /* CHANGE */
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
}

int
main( void )
{
        struct llist *root = NULL;
        char string;

        while( (string = getchar()) != '\n' ) {  /* Optional CHANGE (1) */
                add( &root,string, compare );
        }

        display(root);
        return 0;
}

/* 
 * (1) Using "'\n'" instead of 10 is necessary for readability,
 * portability, and sanity of future maintainers.
 * 
 * Writing getchar() only once is cleaner.
 */
```

Comment: I don't know if I'm following you, shouldn't I be seeing the same character printed out but just repeated in place of the other characters in my string if this were the case?

Comment: No.  You are passing the address of a char to strcmp, which expects a string (a null terminated array of char), so you have u.b.

Answer (score 0):

With your hard coded entry code you are passing in string's to `add` while in your user input code you are only passing in a pointer to a single character.  A `char*` is not necessarily a string in C, it may point to a string, but it doesn't have to.

In C a string is a buffer of characters that ends with a null zero, the character `'\0'` (which is usually just the value 0).  When you are using `getchar` your are passing a pointer to a character - and that character does not have a null zero after it, so it is not a valid C string.

If you want to keep your code using `getchar` you need to use a buffer that will store a null zero after that character.  You can do that will a small array as below:

```
int main(void) {
    struct llist *root = NULL;
    char string[2];

    string[1] = '\0'; // Ensure that we have a null terminated string

    printf("Please enter a string to be sorted alphabetically and displayed with a character count: ");
    string[0] = getchar();

    while (string != '\n'){
    add(&root,string, compare);
    string[0] = getchar();

    }

    display(root);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ok I understand what you are saying, but now the string would be a character pointer, and I'm comparing it to an integer value in 'while (string != '\n')' so I changed it to 'while (string[0] != '\n')' and it compiled, but still ran into the same error with nothing but blank space.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaned-up a few things

1) As @shf301 siad, need to pass a string, not just a pointer to a single `char`.

2) Need to create copies of the string - notice `strdup`.

3) While loop should break on `'\n` and `EO` and maybe `'\0`.  `getchar()` returns an `int` for a reason: `EOF` and `0` to `UCHAR_MAX` (e. g. 255).

4) Should `free()` resources at the end - not shown.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// In case you library does not have strdup() ...
char *strdup(const char *s) {
  if (s == NULL) return NULL;
  size_t siz = strlen(s) + 1;
  char *y = malloc(siz);
  if (y != NULL) {
    memcpy(y, s, siz);
  }
  return y;
}

struct llist {
  char *value;
  struct llist *next;
};

int compare(struct llist *one, struct llist *two) {
  return strcmp(one->value, two->value);
}

void add(struct llist **pp, char *value,
        int(*cmp)(struct llist *l, struct llist *r)) {

  struct llist *new;
  new = malloc(sizeof(*new));
  new->value = strdup(value);

  for (; *pp != NULL; pp = &(*pp)->next) {
    if (cmp(*pp, new) > 0)
      break;
  }

  new->next = *pp;
  *pp = new;
}

void display(const struct llist *ptr) {

  for (; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->next) {
    printf("%s\n", ptr->value);
  }
}

int main(void) {
  struct llist *root = NULL;
  char string[2];
  string[1] = '\0';

  printf("Please enter a string to be sorted alphabetically"
          " and displayed with a character count: ");

  int ch;
  while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n' && ch != '\0') {
    string[0] = ch;
    add(&root, string, compare);
  }

  display(root);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: holy moly it worked....so it all came down to stdup? I never have heard of it before now.  the thing you did with ch makes sense, I never would have thought to make it an int though, it makes sense I guess.  Thank you so much Chux!

Comment: After some time (minutes to days), should an answer well meet your needs, _accept_ it.  Once you earn 15+ points, be sure to up-vote any answers that helped you.